# can a mobile phone access a java servlet program?

Tags: servlets, mobile

I have created a backend server using Java Servlet in PC for an application.
I would like to know if a mobile can use that URL and access the same in the mobile?

Comment: What mobile technology are you talking about exactly? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Assuming you are hosting from your own PC, and your mobile has a webbrowser, probably what you need to do is either connect the mobile to WiFi rather than 3G so its on your LAN, or open the proper ports in your router's firewall to allow external access in to your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access to your servlet from your browser, therefor you can access it programmatically. For example in [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/http/android-how-to-send-http-get-request-to-servlet-using-apache-http-client/) link you can see how you can access to a servlet from android project. You just need to create an GET/POST HTTP request.